# How to get count of data and categorize it using SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have a database as follows:

> [image]

Now I want to get the `COUNT` for Time where categorized into less than or more than 5 s and `GROUP BY` `Name`. Then I need to show the data in gridview.

Can anyone show me the SQL command or any other ways to do so?

Comment: it is much better to say `not equal to 5` than `less than or more than 5 s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is...

```
SELECT Name, case when time<5 then 'less' else '5 or over' end, COUNT(*)  
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Name , case when time<5 then 'less' else '5 or over' end
```

or as columns

```
select name, 
    SUM(case when time<5 then 1 else 0 end) as unders, 
    SUM(case when time>=5 then 1 else 0 end) as overs
from yourtable
group by name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Time) 
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(Time) > 5 OR COUNT(Time) < 5
```

Or

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Time) 
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY Name    
HAVING COUNT(Time) <> 5
```

Comment: better do that in `HAVING COUNT(Time) <> 5` :-)

Comment: @JohnWoo Yup. That is another option :) even better. updating

Comment: @hims056 `WHERE` clause does allow the usage of Aggregate functions such as `SUM`, `COUNT`, etc. :)

Comment: @hims056 much better, btw `+1` for you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
select Name, COUNT(Time) 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Name 
having  COUNT(Time) <>5
```